# Selecting ranges of data in Pandas using duplicated rows, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract from data which has been concatenated into a dataframe, which has a similar pattern repeating throughout.

The data I want to extract will occur throughout the index of the dataframe and begin with 'Staff' and end with 'Total Staff' each time, but of course loc does not work with duplicated data, and my goal is to extract each occurrence of data between Staff and Total Staff.

I was hoping to use the codes outlined in [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) such as the isin function, however surely the same problem would occur in trying to extract from duplicated rows?

Is there a workaround or alternative to using loc to extract ranges using duplicated data?

To show my loc function: frame.loc(["Staff" : "Total Staff"])

[image: made up sample]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a column with only two values: "Staff" and "Total Staff".  Let's say "Total Staff" is the delimiter of each group, so:

```
Staff, Staff, Staff, Total Staff, Staff, Total Staff
```

Then `delim = (ser == "Total Staff").cumsum()`:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2
```

Then `groups = delim.shift().fillna(0).astype(int)`:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
```

Now you can grab sections:

```
for ii in range(groups[-1] + 1):
    section = df[groups == ii]
```

Comment: Clever solution!

Comment: Thanks for your input. How about if there are more values than Staff and Total Staff? How would you indicate Staff as the beginning?

Comment: @Iwan: Sample data please.  You can edit it into the question.

Comment: Why not try a for loop?  Just keep a boolean "am I in a group now" and then a count of which group you're in.  Label the groups, similar to what I did but without vectorization.